# how to redirect/dispatch in php?

Tags: php

I am working on login functionality.

So what I want to do is, on form submission from `login.php` if details are correct it should go to `home.php` else it should go back to `login.php`.

My login processing is on `process.php`. But I don't know how to `redirect/dispatch` to appropriate page from `process.php`.

Comment: -1 for lack of effort. [_other questions_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php), [_another_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871942/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-php?rq=1), [_another_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670910/redirecting-php?rq=1) how many you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  header function like this:

```
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
```

But don't print any html output before calling header function else it will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

`header('Location: http://someweb.com');` will redirect the user.

Comment: The second part of your answer is unture. *"HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to  Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs."* - [PHP Documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this  :

```
<?php
session_start();
//do some login processing

if(login === true){
    exit(header('Location: home.php'));
}else{
    //Extra marks set a reason why failed
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Some error about why it failed';
    exit(header('Location: login.php'));
}
?>
```

`exit(header('Location: *'));` is what your after.

Comment: what diff exit() makes?

Comment: It stops further execution of the script, its best practice because its possible for a client to not redirect before further code is executed.